# Predictive Intelligence - Linking content and product catalogues

Tags: einstein

I'm trying to figure out how I can link a product catalogue and content catalogue to match recommendations based on compatibility.

Example: On a product detail page, I would like to recommend content (FAQ-articles) that is compatable with / related to the product being viewed. But also the other way around. On an FAQ-article page, I would like to be able to recommend products that are related to / compatable with the content.

In the case of only a product catalogue, I would just create an extra column called 'compatability' and base the predictive scenario on 'tag > compatable > same as reference'

However, I would like to cross-reference from content to product catalogue and vice versa.

Does anyone know whether this is possible, and if so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged your question with "predictive-intelligence". I'm going to assume this a reference to a Salesforce Einstein feature If it is, this will be a matter of "training" Salesforce Einstein with data, whether it be pictures, cases, or other information you have that it can consume, your results will be no better than the data you "train" it with. If you don't have valid data that creates the relationships, then you won't be able to produce anything you can rely on. Einstein can't generate relationships that don't exist in the data that's in your database.

Predictive Analysis is more about "likely outcomes", not about whether one product is the equivalent of another. It can determine if a customer who purchased product A is also likely to purchase product B based on the number of existing customers who did that or other market research that you provide it with. It can determine from web views if a visitor might also want to look at document B if they've looked at document C. To do that, you need to be able to feed that data into Einstein for it to analyze. I hope this helps you understand the product a bit better.

Comment: Thanks crmprogdev. I understand the general concept of Einstein and indeed, the relations will be formed based on data. This is all clear to me. From a business perspective, it makes sense to recommend products that are to one another. (of course, Einstein should decide which products should be recommended based on data, but I would like to filter out records that are not compatable). I can do this for either products and content, but these are maintained in separate catalogues. I feel like these separates catalogues function in silo's, but i would like to be able to cross-reference.

Comment: Depending on which Einstein product you're using, you can prepare "datasets" for Einstein to process that will teach" it what these relationships are. Like any computer, Einstein is initially "stupid". It's like a child that needs to be taught the difference between "right" and "wrong". It's up to you to decide what and how you want it to learn. Just be careful what you teach it so it doesn't learn the "incorrect" lessons and become a bit schizophrenic. ;)